# Excel Formula for below description

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's a simple explanation of what I'm having trouble with.

```
In Sheet1
Column H: List of languages (Target Language)
Column G: List of languages (Source Language)

In Sheet2

Column A: List of languages
Column B: List of Region
```

So, i'm looking for a formula in sheet1 column Z where if column H = English (UK) or English (US) or English (Australia) or English (IR) than look at column G & check in sheet2 for column A & B to give Region info.

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like VLOOKUP

Comment: Whats difference between Column H and Column G in sheet 1?

Comment: Column H = Target Language & Column G = Source Language

Answer (score 1):

Type into Z1 and drag down:

```
=if(or(H1="English (UK)",H1="English (US)",H1="English (Australia)",H1="English (IE)"),VLOOKUP(G1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple vlookup and filter combination.

Place the following formula in Z2 cell and copy it down.

`=vlookup(G2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)`

Now apply filter on column H for your desired Target languages viz. English (UK) or English (US) or English (Australia) or English (IR)

Done!

Comment: Thank you. The trick is that when H Column consists of English (UK) or English (US) or English (Australia) or English (IR) it should look at Column H & pull up region info from Sheet2 column B.